# How can a Python script determine when the current time is between two given daily times?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm writing a Python script that is to run continuously, performing some of its functionality only if it determines that the current time is between two daily times. Specifically, the script is given two command line arguments that are both of the form HHMM, where HH is the daily starting hour and MM is minutes and UTC is assumed.

So, for example, the script might be told to run through the day (0900, 1700), or it might be told to run through the night (2200, 0700).

Given such arguments -- that specify times that can be in the current day and the following day -- is there some straightforward way (perhaps using the `datetime` module) for the script to know if the current time is between these two times?

Comment: Yes. Now you just need to code it.

Comment: Consider [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct two datetime objects from your arguments + today's date.

If the "later" one is less then the earlier one then add one day to the later time.  It should now be greater than the early time.

Then compare the current time to see if it is greater than the early time and less than the later time.

Answer (score 0):

start and end can be represented as tuples:

```
start = (9, 0)
end = (17,0)

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().timetuple()[3:5] # gives you (hour,min)
print start <= now <= end
```